# How can I get docker container root's password

Tags: docker

How can I get docker container root's password?

```
[root@localhost train02]# docker exec -it jenkins /bin/bash
[jenkins@89d5aa94e6ec /]ls /root
ls:cannot open directory /root: Permission denied
```

Comment: If you didn't give the sudo permission to account jenkins in the image, then you can't

Answer (score 124, accepted):

If you're using the docker ([>=1.7.0](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#170-2015-06-16)), please pass `-u` option to `docker exec`:

```
docker exec -it -u root jenkins /bin/bash
```

It'll run /bin/bash as root user.

Comment: I met error ````exec: "-u":executable file not found in $PATH````

Comment: @user2492364 Sorry, I put `-u root` in wrong place. Please try the new command.

Comment: Thanks It works!  But still got permission denied when ````ls /root```` Do you know why it happened??It's weired.

Comment: You can check the permission: `stat /root`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It tells how to get a root shell, but not what the default root password is.

Answer (score 0):

FYI / JFR I got this result when tried like this:

```
$ docker-compose exec -it -u root php bash  
Execute a command in a running container  
(further hint suggestions continues...)
```

It accepted when I left out the `-it` switch from the arguments.